# Unmatching Barcode

Tags: usa

Scheduling a J1 visa appointment in ghana, the bar code for my previous B1 visa was generated on the current J1. Been asked to schedule a new appointment after 2 working days.  Would like to know how that happened so that I don't repeat that mistake again.

Comment: This sounds like a production error or printing error from the State department. Not sure if you can do anything about this.

Comment: Perhaps the people to ask are the customer service that handles the application. Their email address is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Only the US visa center would be in a position to identify what might have caused the error, be it human or system:

> **Contact Us**
>
> **Hours of Operation**
>
> English-speaking customer service agents are ready to assist you Monday - Friday from 8:00am to 6:00pm. The call center is closed for Ghanaian and U.S. holidays.
>
> If you need help with your visa application or want to learn more about obtaining a visa to travel to the U.S., please contact us via any of the means shown below. Visa application services call center agents are able to assist you via telephone, chat or email.
>
> **Telephone**: To speak with a call center representative, please contact the call center using any of these numbers:
>
> **Callers in Ghana**:  +233505885956, +233243283510, +233506592787 and +233546719469
>
> **Callers in the US**:  +17035202573
>
> **Email**: To reach a customer service representative via email, please write to us at: support-ghana@ustraveldocs.com

Customer service representatives are also reachable live through **Web call**, **Skype**, and **Chat** functions at http://staging2012.ustraveldocs.com/gh/gh-main-contactus.asp#HoursofOperation